Oracle autonomous db update api not working
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'longTermBackupSchedule')
at getJsonObj (/home/ubuntu/work/OCI-CloudKIT/node_modules/oci-database/lib/model/update-autonomous-database-details.js:73:43)
at Object.serialize (/home/ubuntu/work/OCI-CloudKIT/node_modules/oci-common/lib/object-serializer.js:30:39)
at DatabaseClient. (/home/ubuntu/work/OCI-CloudKIT/node_modules/oci-database/lib/client.js:23798:54)
at Generator.next ()
at /home/ubuntu/work/OCI-CloudKIT/node_modules/oci-database/lib/client.js:40:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (/home/ubuntu/work/OCI-CloudKIT/node_modules/oci-database/lib/client.js:36:12)
at DatabaseClient.updateAutonomousDatabase (/home/ubuntu/work/OCI-CloudKIT/node_modules/oci-database/lib/client.js:23775:16)
at file:///home/ubuntu/work/OCI-CloudKIT/server.js:12859:35
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) im getting this error while usig the update api for oracle autonomous db system the even after providing the parameter the api still not accepting it
